# Regular Expression needed for a pattern like this

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to parse string using regular expressions, in Javascript (not jQuery).

The scenario is that the data is in `div` elements and each `div` contains this kind of HTML in it. There are either no comments, or a numeric value with proper formatting like 1,836 comments

```
User Name 1 | From
Accountant, 5 years of experience
1,836 comments

User Name 3 | From
Accountant, 5 years of experience

User Name 2 | From
Accountant, 5 years of experience
836 comments
```

I just need the regular expression for above comments.

Comment: Provide expected output for sample input.

Comment: Is the number of comments always preceded by the word "experience" ?

Comment: no I have innerHTML of whole div, so i need to check whether this number of comments exits or not, and if exists then what is the value?

Comment: Expected out should be like this
1836
0
836

Comment: @user3675964 Regex can't make up stuff that doesn't exist (`0` doesn't exist, neither does `1836`) `([\d,]+)\s+comments` would match your "comments" field.

Comment: Please tag this question with your programming language

Answer (score 0):

[**RegEx101:**](http://regex101.com/r/oQ1zS7)

```
[0-9,]+    (?# match 1+ 0-9 or , characters)
(?=        (?# start lookahead)
  \s+      (?# match 1+ whitespace characters)
  comment  (?# match comment literally)
  s?       (?# optionally match s literally)
)          (?# end lookahead)
```

---

[**JSFiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/wD722/2/)

```
// Set up variables
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('data'),
    length = elements.length,
    regex = /[0-9,]+(?=\s+comments?)/;

// Loop elements
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var html = elements[i].innerHTML,
        comments = 0;

    // Match against the expression
    var matches = html.match(regex);
    if(matches && matches.length) {
        comments = matches[0].replace(/,/g, ''); // Replace commas
        comments = parseInt(comments);           // String to integer (optional)
    }

    console.log(comments); // 1836, 0, 836
}
```